# How do I directly mock a superclass with python mock?

Tags: python, mocking

I am using the python mock framework for testing (http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) and I want to mock out a superclass and focus on testing the subclasses' added behavior.

(For those interested I have extended *pymongo.collection.Collection* and I want to only test my added behavior.  I do not want to have to run mongodb as another process for testing purposes.)

For this discussion, *A* is the superclass and *B* is the subclass.  Furthermore, I define direct and indirect superclass calls as shown below:

```
class A(object):
    def method(self):
        ...

    def another_method(self):
        ...

class B(A):
    def direct_superclass_call(self):
        ...
        A.method(self)

    def indirect_superclass_call(self):
        ...
        super(A, self).another_method()
```

### Approach #1

Define a mock class for *A* called *MockA* and use *mock.patch* to substitute it for the test at runtime.  This handles direct superclass calls.  Then manipulate B.__bases__ to handle indirect superclass calls. (see below)

The issue that arises is that I have to write *MockA* and in some cases (as in the case for *pymongo.collection.Collection*) this can involve a lot of work to unravel all of the internal calls to mock out.

### Approach #2

The desired approach is to somehow use a mock.Mock() class to handle calls on the the mock just in time, as well as defined return_value or side_effect in place in the test.  In this manner, I have to do less work by avoiding the definition of MockA.

The issue that I am having is that I cannot figure out how to alter B.__bases__ so that an instance of *mock.Mock()* can be put in place as a superclass (I must need to somehow do some direct binding here).  Thus far I have determined, that *super()* examines the MRO and then calls the first class that defines the method in question.  I cannot figure out how to get a superclass to handle the check to it and succeed if it comes across a mock class.  __getattr__ does not seem to be used in this case.  I want super to to think that the method is defined at this point and then use the mock.Mock() functionality as usual.

**How does *super()* discover what attributes are defined within the class in the MRO sequence?  And is there a way for me to interject here and to somehow get it to utilize a *mock.Mock()* on the fly?**

```
import mock

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value      

    def get_value_direct(self):
        return self.value

    def get_value_indirect(self):
        return self.value   

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, value):
        A.__init__(self, value)

    def get_value_direct(self):
        return A.get_value_direct(self)

    def get_value_indirect(self):
        return super(B, self).get_value_indirect()


# approach 1 - use a defined MockA
class MockA(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        pass

    def get_value_direct(self):
        return 0

    def get_value_indirect(self):
        return 0

B.__bases__ = (MockA, )  # - mock superclass 
with mock.patch('__main__.A', MockA):  
    b2 = B(7)
    print '\nApproach 1'
    print 'expected result = 0'
    print 'direct =', b2.get_value_direct()
    print 'indirect =', b2.get_value_indirect()
B.__bases__ = (A, )  # - original superclass 


# approach 2 - use mock module to mock out superclass

# what does XXX need to be below to use mock.Mock()?
#B.__bases__ = (XXX, )
with mock.patch('__main__.A') as mymock:  
    b3 = B(7)
    mymock.get_value_direct.return_value = 0
    mymock.get_value_indirect.return_value = 0
    print '\nApproach 2'
    print 'expected result = 0'
    print 'direct =', b3.get_value_direct()
    print 'indirect =', b3.get_value_indirect() # FAILS HERE as the old superclass is called
#B.__bases__ = (A, )  # - original superclass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played around with mocking out super() as suggested by kindall.  Unfortunately, after a great deal of effort it became quite complicated to handle complex inheritance cases.

After some work I realized that super() accesses the __dict__ of classes directly when resolving attributes through the MRO (it does not do a getattr type of call).  The solution is to extend a mock.MagicMock() object and wrap it with a class to accomplish this.  The wrapped class can then be placed in the __bases__ variable of a subclass.

The wrapped object reflects all defined attributes of the target class to the __dict__ of the wrapping class so that super() calls resolve to the properly patched in attributes within the internal MagicMock().

The following code is the solution that I have found to work thus far. Note that I actually implement this within a context handler.  Also, care has to be taken to patch in the proper namespaces if importing from other modules.

This is a simple example illustrating the approach:

```
from mock import MagicMock
import inspect 


class _WrappedMagicMock(MagicMock):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        object.__setattr__(self, '_mockclass_wrapper', None)
        super(_WrappedMagicMock, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)

    def wrap(self, cls):
        # get defined attribtues of spec class that need to be preset
        base_attrs = dir(type('Dummy', (object,), {}))
        attrs = inspect.getmembers(self._spec_class)
        new_attrs = [a[0] for a in attrs if a[0] not in base_attrs]

        # pre set mocks for attributes in the target mock class
        for name in new_attrs:
            setattr(cls, name, getattr(self, name))

        # eat up any attempts to initialize the target mock class
        setattr(cls, '__init__', lambda *args, **kwds: None)

        object.__setattr__(self, '_mockclass_wrapper', cls)

    def unwrap(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, '_mockclass_wrapper', None)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        super(_WrappedMagicMock, self).__setattr__(name, value)

        # be sure to reflect to changes wrapper class if activated
        if self._mockclass_wrapper is not None:
            setattr(self._mockclass_wrapper, name, value)

    def _get_child_mock(self, **kwds):
        # when created children mocks need only be MagicMocks
        return MagicMock(**kwds)


class A(object):
    x = 1

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def get_value_direct(self):
        return self.value

    def get_value_indirect(self):
        return self.value


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super(B, self).__init__(value)

    def f(self):
        return 2

    def get_value_direct(self):
        return A.get_value_direct(self)

    def get_value_indirect(self):
        return super(B, self).get_value_indirect()

# nominal behavior
b = B(3)
assert b.get_value_direct() == 3
assert b.get_value_indirect() == 3
assert b.f() == 2
assert b.x == 1

# using mock class
MockClass = type('MockClassWrapper', (), {})
mock = _WrappedMagicMock(A)
mock.wrap(MockClass)

# patch the mock in
B.__bases__ = (MockClass, )
A = MockClass

# set values within the mock
mock.x = 0
mock.get_value_direct.return_value = 0
mock.get_value_indirect.return_value = 0

# mocked behavior
b = B(7)
assert b.get_value_direct() == 0
assert b.get_value_indirect() == 0
assert b.f() == 2
assert b.x == 0
```

Answer (score 6):

> is there a way for me to interject here and to somehow get it to utilize a mock.Mock() on the fly?

There may be better approaches, but you can always write your own `super()` and inject it into the module that contains the class you're mocking. Have it return whatever it should based on what's calling it.

You can either just define `super()` in the current namespace (in which case the redefinition only applies to the current module after the definition), or you can `import __builtin__` and apply the redefinition to `__builtin__.super`, in which case it will apply globally in the Python session.

You can capture the original `super` function (if you need to call it from your implementation) using a default argument:

```
def super(type, obj=None, super=super):  
    # inside the function, super refers to the built-in
```

Comment: Hmm ... now you got me thinking.  The concept of redefining a built-in has never occurred to me before. I guess there is not a need to do so often. I have to admit that I would have guessed that the interpreter would not allow you to - but sure enough you can.  So if I were to "patch" super within my context block then I guess I could write my own custom super.  I think I'll play around with this approach a bit and report back.  Thanks.

Comment: check this [response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093526/mocking-the-super-class-calls-on-python/) I did with a working example, it implementes what @kindall suggests.