# Mocking the super class calls on python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am doing some unit testing and at some point I need to mock a `super` call to throw an error, for example:

```
@classmethod
def myfunc(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    try:
        super(MyClass, cls).my_function(args, kwargs)
    except MyException as e:
        #...
```

I am using the [mocker](http://labix.org/mocker#head-83d80b643ee8544628ee7a8301a72443ac51a173) library to mock my objects in general but I haven't found a way to mock this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way, sort of hacky but it works, I'll explain with my example, this is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194847/how-do-i-directly-mock-a-superclass-with-python-mock) response so thanks @kindall:

```
def my_test(self):
    import __builtin__
    from mocker import Mocker, KWARGS, ARGS

    mymocker = mocker.mock()
    mymocker.my_function(ARGS, KWARGS)
    mocker.throw(MyException)

    def mysuper(*args, **kwargs):
        if args and issubclass(MyClass, args[0]):
            return mymocker
        return original_super(*args, **kwargs)

    __builtin__.original_super = super
    __builtin__.super = mysuper

    with mocker:
        MyClass.myfunc()
```

so essentially what I do is check if the `super` call is from the class I want to mock, else just do a normal `super`.

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 64):

Using [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.mock.html) from the standard library I would do something like this.

In your class definition:

```
from somelib import ASuperClass

class MyClass(ASuperClass):
    def my_cool_method(self):
        return super().my_cool_method()
```

In the module where you are calling `MyClass`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from mymodule import MyClass

@patch("mypackage.mymodule.ASuperClass.my_cool_method")
def call_with_mock(mocked_super):
    myinstance = MyClass()
    myinstance.my_cool_method()
    # do stuff with `mocked_super`

call_with_mock()
```

Comment: The problem I have with this is that I have a *lot* of `my_cool_method`s to mock out and it becomes unwieldy. I need a way to just mock the whole class rather than individual methods.

Comment: @Robru You can mock the entire class.

Comment: sure can't. Mocking a superclass makes your class a subclass of a mock, eg it *becomes* a mock and it loses all the methods that you want to test. I ended up creating a class that takes another class as an input, creates all matching methods on itself, as mocks (so it's a real class that contains mocked methods that match the methods of the other class). then I override the base class of the class I'm trying to test, and I'm able to call my methods and confirm that the correct superclass methods are called with the correct arguments -- and raise exceptions when necessary.

Comment: @Robru Sure can. See http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.method_calls and http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.mock_calls

Comment: no that link is not related to what I'm talking about. If I have a `class A:` and a `class B(A):` and I want to test `B` while mocking the methods inherited from `A`, you can't just mock `A`, becuase `B` inherits from `A` and thus itself becomes a mock, which prevents me from calling the methods I want to call, *because* they are mocked. This worked for my use case instead: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cupstream2distro-maintainers/cupstream2distro/trunk/view/970/tests/unit/test_script_build.py#L92

Comment: It appears you can't get the best of both worlds.  If you want to mock out all the methods in your superclass without mocking the subclass, you will have to just mock the methods 1 by 1

Comment: Isn't it somewhat more appropriate to mock each method 1 by 1 given that you're writing tests for _units_? It seems to me to be a better approach to mock exactly what is necessary to mock in order for the unit to be tested.

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone needs another way to solve this mock:

```
# some_package/some_module.py

class MyClass(SuperClass):

    def some_function(self):
        result_super_call = super().function()
```

```
# test_file.py

@patch('some_package.some_module.super')
def test_something(self, mock_super):
    obj = MyClass()
    mock_super().some_function.return_value = None
```

Using Python 3.6

Comment: I ran `test_something()` and got "AttributeError: <class 'some_package.some_class'> does not have the attribute 'super'". Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @mikerodent, 'super' is an attribute on the module that the class is in, not the class. Instead of 'some_package.some_module.some_class', use 'some_package.some_module'.

Comment: Great answer! This as all that is needed to avoid inheriting the mock class and is general enough to work for multiple super() calls throughout the inheriting class.

Answer (score 2):

Python's own Mock class [provides a `spec` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing) that should help with that:

```py
with mock.patch('...ParentClass.myfunc') as mocked_fn:
    mocked_fn.side_effect = MyException()  # Parent's method will raise
    instance = mock.Mock(spec=MyClass)  # Enables using super()
    MyClass.myfunc(instance)  # Will enter your `except` block
```

Answer (score 1):

@Markus is looking in the right place.  So long as you're unit testing (i.e. there's only one call to `super`), you can mock `__builtin__.super` as in:

```
with mock.patch('__builtin__.super') as mock_super:
    mock_super.side_effect = TypeError
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
        obj.call_with_super()
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to reference `builtins.super` instead of `__builtin__.super`. I'm assuming this is a Python 3 thing.

Answer (score -1):

Well, then you need to mock the `my_function` method of the superclass of `MyClass` to blow up.

Comment: I know I can mock something in there to blow up, I am just curious about how to mock the `super` class call, this should be possible. Thanks for the idea thou.

Comment: You mean to mock the `super` callable itself? I think this will cause to raise exceptions on more places than you'd like.

Comment: yea, I know is not something trivial :s