# Nose test superclass calls and inherited classes

Tags: python, inheritance, nose

**Question**
How may I test a class and its methods that has inherited from another Superclass through a `super()` call?

**Example**

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # do something with x and y

    def aMethod(self, param1):
        # do stuff with param1

class B(A):
    def bMethod1(self, param2):
        # do stuff with self and param2
        super(B, self).aMethod(param2)

    def bMethod2(self, myDict):
        # do stuff with myDict
        return myDict
```

And would it be the same if I had for example, `class A(Z)` (inheritance from `class Z()`) and then `class B(A)` ?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22411552/2100933) is very similar to what I'm looking for, but it's for Mocking!

**Edit**
So I would have something like this for my Nose test:

```
class Test_B(Object):
    # All of the setup and teardown defs go here...
    def test_bMethod2(self):
        b = B()
        dict = { 'a' : '1', 'b' : '2' } # and so on...
        assert_equal(b.bMethod2(dict), dict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way of doing so is:

```
class Test_B(Object):
# All of the setup and teardown defs go here...
def test_bMethod2(self):
    a, b, param = "",
    dict = { 'a' : '1', 'b' : '2' }
    # Instantiating B with its super params
    klass = B(a, b)
    # Calling class B's bMethod1() with required params 
    # to pass onto its super class' method (here: aMethod())
    klass.bMethod1(param)
    assert_equal(klass.bMethod2(dict), dict)
```

Hope this helps someone else.