# Django tests - patch object in all tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing, python-mock

I need to create some kind of `MockMixin` for my tests. It should include mocks for everything that calls external sources.
For example, each time I save model in admin panel I call some remote URLs. It would be good, to have that mocked and use like that:

```
class ExampleTestCase(MockedTestCase):
    # tests
```

So each time I save model in admin, for example in functional tests, this mock is applied instead of calling remote URLs.

Is that actually possible? I'm able to do that for 1 particular test, that is not a problem. But it'd be more useful to have some global mock because I use it a lot.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

According to the [`mock` documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#mock.patch):

> Patch can be used as a TestCase class decorator. It works by
> decorating each test method in the class. This reduces the boilerplate
> code when your test methods share a common patchings set.

This basically means that you can create a base test class with `@patch` decorator applied on it that would mock your external calls while every test method inside would be executed.

Also, you can use [`start()` and `stop()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop) patcher's methods in `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods respectively:

```
class BaseTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.patcher = patch('mymodule.foo')
        self.mock_foo = self.patcher.start()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.patcher.stop()
```

Comment: And that also means I have to decorate each of my test cases, and not the ```Mixin``` test class. It's also quite inconvenient that I have to put additional parameter for each test method. But it's better than nothing.

Comment: @galozek please see the relevant topics: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219967/how-to-mock-a-base-class-with-python-mock-library) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194847/how-do-i-directly-mock-a-superclass-with-python-mock).

Comment: the 2nd solution worked. I tried that approach but was missing ```start()```/```stop()``` part. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you might be better off using `self.addCleanup(self.patcher.stop)` instead of doing it in `tearDown` since cleanup gets run whether or not there is an exception.  See @Meistro's answer.

Comment: Don't forget to include imports: `from unittest import TestCase`, `from import unittest.mock import patch`

Answer (score 37):

Just to add to [alecxe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25857701/3357935), if you are using `teardown()` then [according to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-methods-start-and-stop)

> you must ensure that the patching is “undone” by calling `stop`. This can be fiddlier than you might think, because if an exception is raised in the `setUp` then `tearDown` is not called.

If an exception is raised in your tests, your patching won't be undone. A better way would be to call [`addCleanup()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addCleanup) inside your `setUp()`. Then you can omit the `tearDown()` method altogether.

```
class BaseTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.patcher = patch('mymodule.foo')
        self.mock_foo = self.patcher.start()
        self.addCleanup(self.patcher.stop) # add this line
```

Comment: `tearDown` will always be called, even if your tests raise an exception.

Comment: From the docs: "If setUp() fails, meaning that tearDown() is not called, then any cleanup functions added will still be called." So it's still better to call `addCleanup` than hope that no exceptions are raised in `setUp`.

Comment: Don't forget to include imports: `from unittest import TestCase`, `from import unittest.mock import patch`

Comment: wrt what @Meistro mentioned above... make sure that the cleanup hook is added ASAP within the `setUp` method, otherwise, if it fails before the hook is added, it'll be useless

Answer (score 6):

I ended up creating a test runner to serve my purpose. I needed to mock the file storage so that images do not actually write to the file system while testing. The images object is being called in many tests thus patching each class would not be `DRY`. Also, I noticed that mocking the file itself would leave it on the system in case the test failed. But this method didn't.

I created a file `runner.py` in the project root

```py
# runner.py
from unittest.mock import patch

from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner

from myapp.factories import ImageFactory


class UnitTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):

    @patch('django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage.save')
    def run_tests(self, test_labels, mock_save, extra_tests=None, **kwargs):
        mock_save.return_value = ImageFactory.get_image()
        return super().run_tests(test_labels, extra_tests=None, **kwargs)
```

Then I would run my tests using `python manage.py tests --testrunner=runner.UnitTestRunner`

---

Just for clarity the `ImageFactory.get_image` method is a custom method

```py
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from factory.django import DjangoModelFactory
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image as PilImage
from random import randint

class ImageFactory(DjangoModelFactory):

    @classmethod
    def get_image(cls, name='trial', extension='png', size=None):
        if size is None:
            width = randint(20, 1000)
            height = randint(20, 1000)
            size = (width, height)

        color = (256, 0, 0)

        file_obj = BytesIO()
        image = PilImage.new("RGBA", size=size, color=color)
        image.save(file_obj, extension)
        file_obj.seek(0)
        return ContentFile(file_obj.read(), f'{name}.{extension}')
```